# Cannot execute rake db:seed, receive PG::InvalidTimeZoneDisplacementValue: ERROR

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I run rake db:seed I am receiving an error, which I am assuming may have something to do with date objects being built as attributes on the models I am creating in the seeds.rb. If this is the reason, is there a way around it? Here is the error output:

```
rake aborted!
PG::InvalidTimeZoneDisplacementValue: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "-4712-01-01"
: INSERT INTO "courses" ("code", "created_at", "description", "end_on", "image_content_type", "image_file_name", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "instructor_token", "name", "public", "school", "start_on", "student_token", "syllabus", "ta_token", "term", "updated_at", "year") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19) RETURNING "id"
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1174:in `get_last_result'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1174:in `exec_cache'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:63:in `exec_insert'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:367:in `create'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:58:in `create'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `block in create'
/Users/evankline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2393321980833873965__create__2992353098426140512__callbacks'
```

I have seen this error discussed in relation to Heroku, but nothing about it occurring on a local machine. Most answers were related to switching to Ruby 1.9.2, however, this throws errors because several of the gems I am using in the app require Ruby 1.9.3 or greater. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL wasn't recognizing the Date as valid input. By changing the following:

```
Date.new(2014,1,17)
```

to:

```
Date.parse("2014-1-17")
```

I was able to get the seeds to populate the db.

Comment: My problem was that I wanted today's date, and was passing no param. I should have used `Date.today`.